# TypeError: user.hasPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript

I can't get the if(user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) to work can anyone please help me?

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'mute')){

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first();

let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');

if(!role) message.guild.createRole({name: 'Muted'});

if(user.bot){

return message.channel.send('I cant mute ${user} because he is a bot');
}

if(user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {    <-- this line is the error

return message.channel.send('I cant mute ${user} because he is staff');
}

if(!user){
    message.channel.send(`There's no person to mute tho`);
}
message.guild.channels.forEach(f => {
    f.overwritePermissions(role, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false
    });
    user.addRole(role).catch(console.error);

});
 message.channel.send(`I muted ${user}`);
}
});

client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'unmute')){
    message.mentions.members.first();

let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'muted');
if(!user.roles.has(role)) {
return message.channel.send('He is not muted');
}
user.removeRole(role).then(message.channel.send(`Unmuted ${user}`));

}
});
```

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(user)` right above the line where the error occurs and verify that it has a `hasPermission()` method?

Comment: Have you tried writing ADMINISTRATOR without quotes? If it's a TypeError, it may be because the script recognizes the parameter as a string.